# Hiding Columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide columns based on a value from another sheet. I have read several articles and don't feel like this is very difficult but am having some issues. When the value in Sheets("Data").Cells(2, 3) is 1 everything works fine but when I change it to 2,3 or 4 the code somehow highlights the entire spreadsheet and "hides" everything. Makes no sense. Below is one version using If..Then. I tried the same thing with select case and this same issue occurs.

```
Sub test()
   Dim choice As Integer
   Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("O:S").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    choice = CInt(Sheets("Data").Cells(2, 3))

If choice = 1 Then
    Range("O:P").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf choice = 2 Then
    Range("Q:Q").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf choice = 3 Then
    Range("R:R").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf choice = 4 Then
    Range("S:S").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If
Sheets("Summary").Cells(1, 1).Select
```

Comment: It works fine for me.  Hides your columns then unhides then 1 at a time.

Comment: Odd... I wonder what is different about how I have set up my spreadsheet. When I step through using F8 line     Range("O:S").Select highlights "A:S" instead... then the next line Hides those columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting rid of selections. This code works for me.

```
Sub test()
    Dim choice As Integer
    Sheets("Summary").Activate
    range("O:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    choice = CInt(Sheets("Data").Cells(2, 3))

If choice = 1 Then
    range("O:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf choice = 2 Then
    range("Q:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf choice = 3 Then
    range("R:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ElseIf choice = 4 Then
    range("S:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If
Sheets("Summary").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```